# Strange cropping behaviour

Tags: ios, encoding, camera, avassetexportsession

When trying to re-encode a MOV to MP4 using SDAVAssetExportSession with example from [readme](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession/blob/master/README.md), I get borders on left and right with rear camera device, and a square crop with front camera.

Without any re-encoding, my player (PBJVideoPlayerController, using AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill) displays correctly the fullscreen video.

I guess there is something wrong with renderSize of SDAVAssetExportSession, but I don't really understand why nobody else seems to have the problem.

Here are screenshots with front and rear camera after re-encoding :

Screenshot of video without re-encoding, rear camera (perfectly fullscreen):
[image: Screenshot of video without re-encoding, rear camera (perfectly fullscreen)]

Screenshot of video with re-encoding, rear camera:
[image: Screenshot of video with re-encoding, rear camera]

Screenshot of video with re-encoding, front camera
[image: Screenshot of video with re-encoding, front camera]

As you can see, the player shouldn't be the problem as everything is ok without re encoding. But after exporting, borders appears with rear, and I-don't-know-really-know-what-happens with front camera...

Any help ?

Thanks !

PS : Like my coffee bowl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using SDAVAssetExportSession as well and I've realized that bad video cropping will occur if you give a portrait video more width than height and deviate from the aspect ratio that it needs. The same will occur for a landscape video if you give it more height than width.

My solution is to get the videos aspect ratio and current dimensions first before transcoding and then calculate a smaller width and height based off its current dimensions in order to maintain the aspect ratio. This will keep the resulting video from having black borders.

Update: Here is the relevant code -

This shows how to resize and keep the aspect ratio and avoid cropping issues.  Note that the `width` and `height` are integer variables controlled by the user.  If they aren't provided I transcode with the original video width and height.

```
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:assetPath] options:nil];

NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", cacheDir, videoFileName, outputExtension];
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];

NSArray *tracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVAssetTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
CGSize mediaSize = track.naturalSize;

float videoWidth = mediaSize.width;
float videoHeight = mediaSize.height;
float aspectRatio = videoWidth / videoHeight;
int newWidth = (width && height) ? height * aspectRatio : videoWidth;
int newHeight = (width && height) ? newWidth / aspectRatio : videoHeight;

NSLog(@"input videoWidth: %f", videoWidth);
NSLog(@"input videoHeight: %f", videoHeight);
NSLog(@"output newWidth: %d", newWidth);
NSLog(@"output newHeight: %d", newHeight);

SDAVAssetExportSession *encoder = [SDAVAssetExportSession.alloc initWithAsset:avAsset];
encoder.outputFileType = stringOutputFileType;
encoder.outputURL = outputURL;
encoder.videoSettings = @
{
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: newWidth],
    AVVideoHeightKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: newHeight],
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @
    {
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: videoBitRate],
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High40
    },
};
```

Comment: Didn't checked, but marked as accepted answer as if that works as expected, that's what I wanted when I needed it.